# Solve the enclosing parallel error when using OpenMP in R

Tags: c, r, openmp, r-package

I try to call `OpenMP` codes in my `R` package. The OpenMP region in a `fun.c` file under the `src` directory is like:

```
    static void mp_func(double *x, double *a, double *b,
                           double *den, int *P) {
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(P[0]) default(none)          \
            firstprivate(length, q, a, b, isLog, lowTail, cdf, R_NaN) private(i) \
                reduction(||:naflag)
                for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
                    ...
                    if(some condition) den[i] = R_NaN;
                    ...
                    if(some condition) den[i] = R_NegInf;
                }
    }
```

However, when I run `R CMD CHECK`, `it gives error message that:

```
 enclosing parallel;
```

and

```
R_NaN not specified in enclosing parallel;
```

I don't think including `R_NaN` and `R_NegInf` in the `private` clause is possible, so how can I solve it? Should I wrap all operation part into a function and call this function in the OpenMP region?

Comment: You should learn how to use OpenMP first with C before you try to use it with R. You should also provide a complete code example (e.g. where to you define the iterator `i`). I think you should also show how you would like to call this function from R. Also, I don't see how R is going to know about `mp_func` since you made it static. Improve your question and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is solved by add `R_NaN` and such in `firstprivate` clause. The reason to do so is that `R_NaN` and `R_NegInf` are global variables called via `external` declarations from the included header file `R.h`.

Comment: please provide an example